# ElasticSearch - how to return a single value from a list if there is a match

Tags: indexing, mapping, elasticsearch

I'm trying to return a single value if I search on a field that contains a list. `tags` is my list and I have three values in it one, two and three.

```
 tags : ["one", "two", "three"]
```

If I do a search on the `tags` field for "two" I would like to only return the "two" value in the results.

What is the correct mapping to achieve this, should I use a nested object? If so, is it possible to do so with my current mapping below?

```
{
  "document": {
      "properties": {
        "tags":{
           "type": "multi_field",
           "fields":{
             "tags" {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "analyzed"
             },
             "untouched": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
             }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it's not possible with nested objects yet https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3022  (nor any other mapping afaik)